# Google Drive C# Exception fired 'Application not found'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, frameworks, google-drive-api

[image]

Error shown in screenshot - please help me.

Comment: Please read how to ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  and this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: In other application execute but on my machine exception fired.

Comment: Does your machine have client_secret.json and drive-dotnet-quickstart.json on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 
new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive, DriveService.Scope.DriveFile }

Instead of just "Scopes"